# Unit quaternion ball is compact and connected?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let$$\mathbb{U} := \{x \in \mathbb{H} : |x| = 1\}.$$This is a group under multiplication. What is the easiest way to see that $\mathbb{U}$ is a compact and connected subset of $\mathbb{H}\cong \mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: When you identify $\Bbb{H}$ with $\Bbb{R}^4$ (this is an isometry) your set $\Bbb{U}$ is identified with the 4D unit sphere $S^3$. Does that help?

Comment: Isn't this just the unit sphere in the Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^4$. Then it is connected like every unit sphere $S^n$. You could express it as the union of the two hemispheres, and each is connected being homeomorphic to the unit ball $D^n$.

Comment: Are you assuming a particular topology on $\mathbb H$. Otherwise use Heine-Borel for compactness.

Comment: I think it I not hard to show that $S^3$ is path-connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment a unit quaternion $\mathbf{u}=a\mathbf{i}+b\mathbf{j}+c\mathbf{k}$ is such that $|\mathbf{u}|=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$

so your set $\mathbb{U}$ is isomorphic tho the unit sphere $S^3$ and this is connected as you can see at [How do you prove that the 3-sphere is connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136830/how-do-you-prove-that-the-3-sphere-is-connected)